# Flutter: How to make a button like this?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, button, flutter-layout

I tried to use `TextButton.Icon` to make the effect as following.
But I found that the words can only be at the left or right of the icon. How can I put the words under the icon like this?

[image]

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[MCVE]". We appreciate that you might be new, but we do expect evidence of the effort you've put into this. Where did you search? Why didn't it help? If it did, where is the code you wrote to test what you learned? If you didn't write code, why not? What is the minimal code that demonstrates the problem you encountered, along with the explanation of the problem, and the minimal input data and the expected result? Without that, it's hard to help you.

Comment: please do accept the answer, if it helped you!

Answer (score 1):

1. the simplest way to create such things is to use column and row widget properly.
2. i added a full code with the screenshot check it below
   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRzy9.png
3. created a reusable widget for icon with button and added it in my main class i.e test class

```
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  const Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 10,),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                IconWithTextButton(icon:const Icon(Icons.lock, color: Colors.red,),text: "Lock",onClicked: (){},),
                IconWithTextButton(icon:const Icon(Icons.alarm, color: Colors.amber),text: "Alarm",onClicked: (){},),
                IconWithTextButton(icon:const Icon(Icons.call, color: Colors.green),text: "call",onClicked: (){},),
                IconWithTextButton(icon:const Icon(Icons.wrong_location_sharp, color: Colors.greenAccent),text: "location",onClicked: (){},),
                IconWithTextButton(icon:const Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.tealAccent),text: "Add",onClicked: (){},),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20,),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                IconWithTextButton(icon: const Icon(Icons.lock, color: Colors.red,),text: "Lock",onClicked: (){},),
                IconWithTextButton(icon:const Icon(Icons.alarm, color: Colors.amber),text: "Alarm",onClicked: (){},),
                IconWithTextButton(icon:const Icon(Icons.call, color: Colors.green),text: "call",onClicked: (){},),
                IconWithTextButton(icon:const Icon(Icons.wrong_location_sharp, color: Colors.greenAccent),text: "location",onClicked: (){},),
                IconWithTextButton(icon:const Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.tealAccent),text: "Add",onClicked: (){},),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

1. this is reusable widget with reusable text, reusable onclick and reusable icon

```
class IconWithTextButton extends StatelessWidget {
  String text;
  Icon icon;
  VoidCallback onClicked;
  IconWithTextButton({Key? key, required this.text, required this.onClicked, required this.icon}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onClicked,
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            icon,
            const SizedBox(height: 10,),
            Text(text),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Column Widget and populate its children with Icon and TextField.
Then Wrap the whole widget with GestureDetector for on pressed functionality.
You can also wrap it with InkWell and Material to get splash effect like in other buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You need not wrap with column.

```
TextButton(
        onPressed:(){},
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Icon(Icons.play_arrow,color:Colors.green),
            Text(
              'Hello',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I think GirdView Widget  the best way to make button like this-

```
GridView.count(
    crossAxisCount: 4,
    children:  List<Widget>.generate(16, (index) {
      return  GridTile(
        child:GestureDetector(  
          onTap:(){
            print(index.toString());
          },
      child:    Card(
          color: Colors.blue.shade200,
          child:  Column(
            children:[  Text('tile $index'),
                         Icon(Icons.alarm)
          ])
        )),
     );
    }),
  ),
```

With help of index parameter you can pass function  according to button type.